# Impressão em Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, impressão, lado-do-cliente

Estou com o seguinte problema, preciso fazer a impressão de dados que são gerados pela minha aplicação Ruby on Rails, porém, essa impressão deve ser feita direta na porta USB/Serial do cliente.

A impressora utilizada será uma **Zebra**.

Tentei utilizar o **qz print**, porém, os navegadores não estão mais suportando o Java.

Existe alguma solução para o meu problema?

Comment: Aqui na empresa onde trabalho, tivemos esta mesma necessidade, então foi desenvolvido uma aplicação em java que fica escutando uma porta e quando recebe um parâmetro (um id), pegas as informações e imprime. Tem a diferença de ser em uma rede interna, mas já é um caminho para se começar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente não tem como realizar isso utilizando qualquer aplicação *server side*, exceto se você desenvolver um cliente que rode localmente na máquina do usuário e receba essa informação por uma conexão com seu servidor.